# Best Spring MVC,Hibernate,Mysql & Maven application hosting server

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, heroku, openshift, azure-web-app-service

I have completed my first web & Mobile project in Spring mvc 3.2.6 + Hibernate + Maven,Mysql & Rest Services.
Now i want to host the application.So that i can hit the webservice via mobile & host the web application.While browsing the google found the following link.

http://aws.amazon.com/free/

https://www.openshift.com/

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/

http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/private

https://www.heroku.com/pricing

https://appengine.google.com/start

So could you please anyone guide which one of the above server is good to host.Right now i am planning to use FREE version of the above server and in future i may use a paid version.Could  anyone please which one is best?

I appreciate your answers & suggestion!!!Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can say for Openshift. The best features it gave to you is:

- No credit card required
- No trial time
- Doesn't need to sleep
- Can scale, you can use up to 3 small gears on free plan, all loadbalanced by default
- Many cartridges (like a pre-built package with servers) like MySQL, Mongo, RedisCloud, AMQPCloud, a bunch of others services using the Marketplace with a lot of free ones
- Sleep when nobody is using, when someone hit a request the server goes on again , also auto scale up and down
- Easy setup and Java ApplicationServers support (Tomcat, JBoss, Wildfly***)
- Easy build customization via hooks
- You can upgrade to *bronze* plan without paying a coin using the free gears you have, and you get alot of features
- Runs on AWS Infrastructure

**EDIT**

Think of *Gears* as machines, it's just a fancy name they give to it, like Heroku named theirs *Dynos*

Price plans are located [here](https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing/plan-comparison) with side by side comparison. You can check the marketplace offers [here](https://marketplace.openshift.com/home). Also [they have some quick starters](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/languages/java), all Java cartridges comes with Java 7 and Maven 3 installed by default. See [here](https://www.openshift.com/products/technologies) for more detailed tech.

They have a [developers site](https://developers.openshift.com/) with content to get started, help and documentation

** Small gears are machines with 1 CPU, 512Mb of RAM and 1GB disk

*** Wildfly on a free plan takes so much disk space, then is pratical impossible to use, but for paid plans is awesome

Comment: Many thanks for your answer could you please send me the link for list of features supported by openShift.Also i am unable to understand the  "Gears" concept.How much Bandwidth it will support for Free Plan?It will support Maven?Sorry for asking so much question,Really i am new to this environment,Also switching the server is not so easy.So i want to select the best suit server.

Comment: @VelNaga no problem, OpenShift doesn't lock you, you don't even need any customizations on your maven deployment, if you need, it's just a folder, you don't touch your code (unless you need setup env vars), with built-in Git support it's just download your code and move on with another provider.